# get Unauthorized when trying to send post request to mercure hub

Tags: symfony, postman, mercure

I'm working with mercure to get real time response.

i configured mercure with docker :

```
mercure:
    container_name: mercure
    image: dunglas/mercure
    restart: always
    environment:
      PUBLISHER_JWT_KEY: mySecretKeyPublisher
      SUBSCRIBER_JWT_KEY: mySecretKeySubscriber
      ALLOW_ANONYMOUS: 1
      CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS: "*"
    networks:
      - proxy
```

my dev url to test mercure is :

```
http://mercure.localhost/.well-known/mercure
```

I generated token using https://jwt.io/

I used this payload :

```
{
    "mercure": {
        "publish": ["*"]
    }
}
```

and mySecretKeyPublisher :

[image]

Now i test with postman :

[image]
[image]
[image]

I got always : Unauthorized

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the **key=** in the token in POSTMAN.
You just need to specify the generated JWT token.